# Unreachable statement and break code connecting to other blocks of code

Tags: break, unreachable-statement

Can someone please explain to me why this break code connects to another block of code and what I can do to resolve this? I'm kinda new to programming. I've tried rearranging it but it doesn't execute the other code. The error message says "unreachable statement."

Comment: you forgot to include the code

Comment: Do not use control structures like `if`, `for` and `while` without curly braces, it might mislead you in the beginning of programming where blocks start and end. You have a `break` statement which leaves some block (we can't see), so any code inside the current block after the `break` statement is "unreachable", hence the error message.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.